# How much time does fibonacci algorithm take to compute F(n)

Tags: algorithm, fibonacci

I was reading '8.1.1 Fibonacci numbers by recursion' section in 'The algorithm design manual' book by Skiena.

I could not able to understand below paragraph in this section.

**How much time does this algorithm take to compute F(n)? Since Fn+1/Fn ≈
φ = (1+√5)/2 ≈ 1.61803, this means that Fn > 1.6^n. Since our recursion tree has
only 0 and 1 as leaves, summing up to such a large number means we must have at
least 1.6n leaves or procedure calls! This humble little program takes exponential time to run!**

Can any one explain my below questions from this paragraph.

- Why is Fn+1/Fn used to calculate algorithm time?
- Why Fn > 1.6^n
- How we will get 1.6n leaves or procedures calls?

Please explain by taking example as F(4)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it relates to [computer science](http://cs.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Complexity of naive Fibonacci recursion is...Fibonacci!

Comment: Take a look [here](http://marcodiiga.github.io/linear-recurrence-relations) for an interesting way of dealing with Fibonacci calculations.

Comment: Which Fibonacci algorithm?

Answer (score 1):

Here's my answer for my question.
If you use recursion to compute fibonacci numbers, the computation time is `F(N)+F(N-1)+F(N-2)+...+F(1) = F(N+2)-2 = O(F(N+2)).` 
[Binet's Formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BinetsFibonacciNumberFormula.html) proves `F(N) nearly equal sqrt(1/5) * φ^N`, and this formula also prove this.

- F(k+1)/F(k) nearly equal φ.
- You can prove F(k) >= 1.6^k if you check for small k.

But I suggest to calculate fibonacci numbers for this algorithm.

**1. Using Dynamic Programming** 
Fibonacci Sequence can compute for dynamic programming and the time is O(N). 
It is obvious because there is a relation F(N)=F(N-1)+F(N-2).

**2. Using Matrix Exponentation** 
Actually, `( (1 1) (1 0) )^N = ( (F(N+2) F(N+1)) (F(N+1) F(N)) ).` 
If you use exponentation-by-squaring algorithm, you can compute its value for O(log N), so you can compute F(N) for O(log(N)).

In conclusion, Binet's formula is not good because it uses floating-point value, so it causes precision error. 
I suggest that using dynamic programming or matrix exponentation is good for this problem.

Comment: Suggesting a faster algorithms does not answer the question.

Comment: @tobias_k I edited and I also answered the question.

Comment: Don't forget simple iteration, which is much better than the dynamic programming or recursive methods.

Comment: The time isn't quite `O(N)` because the numbers themselves get bigger.

Comment: I assumed that calculating basic arithmetic operation can do in O(1).

Answer (score 1):

I'm switching from n to m for the first part of the answer.

F(m+1)/F(m) is a ratio being used to get an approximate value for F(m), not the time. Starting at m >= 1, as m increases, the ratio F(m+1)/F(m) quickly converges towards φ = (1+sqrt(5))/2 ~= 1.61803. This can be restated as F(m+1) ~= φ F(m). Then F(m+2) ~= φ F(m+1) ~= φ (φ F(m)) ~= φ^2 F(m), and in general F(m+k) ~= φ^k F(m), a reasonable approximation for m >= 10, as  shown in the table at the end of this answer. The paragraph then makes a sudden leap to the statement that F(n) > 1.6^n, which is only true for n >= 72.

The paragraph then addresses the recursion tree, which only involves addition, and notes that the leaf nodes of the recursion tree only return 0 (F(0)) or 1 (F(1)), so you would need at least 1.6^n (not 1.6n) leaf nodes (1.6^n leaf nodes that return 1) to produce a sum >= 1.6^n. (Again note that F(n) > 1.6^n is only true for n >= 72).

As for a faster algorithm, a Lucas sequence method is similar to an optimized matrix exponentiation by squaring method. The max value for 64 bit unsigned integer is fib(93) == 12200160415121876738 (which would take 7 loops in the code below).

```
/* lucas sequence method */
uint64_t fib(uint64_t n) {
    uint64_t a, b, p, q, aq, qq;
    a = q = 1;
    b = p = 0;
    while(1){
        if (n & 1) {
            aq = a*q;
            a = b*q + aq + a*p;
            b = b*p + aq;
        }
        n >>= 1;
        if (n == 0)
            break;
        qq = q*q;
        q = p*q*2 + qq;
        p = p*p + qq;
    }
    return b;
}
```

To give an idea of how accurate the approximation F(m+k) ~= φ^k F(m) is, using F(100) as a test case versus values of m (10, 20, 30, 40).

```
F(100)/(φ^90 F(10)) ~= 1.0000661
F(100)/(φ^80 F(20)) ~= 1.00000000437
F(100)/(φ^70 F(30)) ~= 1.000000000000289
F(100)/(φ^60 F(40)) ~= 1.0000000000000000191
```

Answer (score -1):

this is a highly optimized fibonacci function for **python 3.0**

```
def fibonacci_optimized(n):
    if n <= 0:
        return 0

    def matrix_multiply(a, b):
        c = [[0, 0], [0, 0]]
        for i in range(2):
            for j in range(2):
                for k in range(2):
                    c[i][j] += a[i][k] * b[k][j]
        return c

    def matrix_power(matrix, n):
        if n == 1:
            return matrix
        if n % 2 == 0:
            matrix_half = matrix_power(matrix, n // 2)
            return matrix_multiply(matrix_half, matrix_half)
        else:
            matrix_half = matrix_power(matrix, (n - 1) // 2)
            return matrix_multiply(matrix_multiply(matrix_half, matrix_half), matrix)

    base_matrix = [[1, 1], [1, 0]]
    result_matrix = matrix_power(base_matrix, n - 1)
    return result_matrix[0][0]
```

**example**:

import performance counter:

```
from time import perf_counter
```

code:

```
inp = int(input("number to convert: "))
start = perf_counter()
fib = fibonacci_optimized(inp)
end = perf_counter()

print(f"fibonacci output: {fib}")
print(f"time it took: {end-start}")
```

*output*:

```
number to convert: 1000
fibonacci output: 43466557686937456435688527675040625802564660517371780402481729089536555417949051890403879840079255169295922593080322634775209689623239873322471161642996440906533187938298969649928516003704476137795166849228875
time it took: 9.839999999972093e-05
```

In roughly less than **0.3 seconds**, the program was able to compute the **Fibonacci sequence for one million** and produce a result spanning 208,988 characters.

Comment: "Highly optimized" and "python" in one sentence doesn't add up.

Comment: @infinitezero Please show us your faster program then. How long does it take for this?

Comment: @Kelly python is notoriously slow, so any optimisation is negligible, because essentially you're tuning an old tractor. Maybe you'll get it up to 60mph, but there's other languages that start at 180 and there's plenty of room above. In any case, Mathematica's built in calculates Fib(10^6) in 0.0114s, so almost 30times faster.

Comment: @infinitezero Almost all the work here is done by the pure C code computing the products/sums, though. About 99.97% of those 0.3 seconds are in that pure C, only ~0.0001 seconds are Python interpretation. So are you referring to Python's C code speed? I don't have Mathematica, is there a good website that offers it? And what's the code to compute and print the value? I tried [this](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78/z@gKDOvJNotM0nD0CDOTDP2/38A) but it doesn't work.

Comment: @KellyBundy exactly my point, it's not python, it's a precompiled library. Try this: `Print[Fibonacci[10^6]]`

Comment: @KellyBundy or even better: `Print[AbsoluteTiming[Fibonacci[10^6]]]`

Comment: @infinitezero But Python's C code is precompiled as well. The reason it's slower is that it's a general-purpose language, so it doesn't try to implement all the fastest known multiplication/addition algorithms. If you want those, just import gmpy2 (although frustratingly I'm on a phone and can't find an online service supporting it, even replit.com gives me an error...). Thanks for the code, that works. Although the question is about an **algorithm**, and purely calling a built in function hardly qualifies as that :-)

Comment: @infinitezero This code takes me ~0.014 seconds for F_1000000 at replit now, just by using gmpy2's `mpz` instead of Python's built-in ints. (Was able to pip-install it at replit after all.)